# How can I reference a cell from a different cell

Tags: excel

How can I reference a cell from a different cell?

For eg:

I want to reference Cell A1 = B1, But dont want any formulas/logic in Cell A1. The formula/logic can be in any other cell.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set cell A1 equal to the value in cell B1, without having the formula to do so *in* cell A1?

Comment: @JYelton Yes, nothing in Cell A1

Comment: User793468, please remember to upvote/accept comments that you find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change a cell value without having a formula in the same cell, you'll likely need to use VBA. For example:

At [Wrox Programmer-to-Programmer](http://p2p.wrox.com/excel-vba/37251-excel-putting-result-formula-another-cell.html), Maccas posts the following example:

```
Sub UpdateVal()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value
End Sub
```

One question that comes to mind however, is *why* you don't want a formula in cell A1?

Something like `=IF(some_condition, B1, "")` would leave cell A1 blank unless it met some condition, but populate it with B1's value otherwise.

Comment: ^This...no other way to do it without there being a formula present.

Comment: Plus, using VBA would require some event to trigger the update when the value of cell B1 changed

Comment: The IF statement actually does not leave it *EMPTY*. Sometimes, and empty cell is required if some condition is met.